# Отправка формы Ajax с валидацией + подтягивание переменных

Tags: php, javascript, html

Возможно вопрос глупый, но я еще новичек, поэтому не могу справиться уже второй день. Не получается одновременно принять на почту и данные по форме и текстовые данные с блока.

Основная проблема начинается в файле **JS** со строки  **$.post('Post_Constructor.php'...**

1. Если удалю **'&item_price=' + $('#price').text()**

   - Приходят на емейл данные по форме!
2. А если удалю **$('#contruct-from').serializeArray()**

   - Приходит на емейл текстовое содержимое **`<span id="price">900</span>`**
3. Если ничего не удалять, тогда инспектор браузера покажет вот что:

**item_price:900
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]**

... и на форму придёт нужное мне число 900 и строка "объектов".

Насколько мне известно дело не с обработчиком, а в неправильной передаче данных.

**HTML**

```
<span id="price">900</span>
<form id="contruct-from">
   <input name="namecontr">
   <input name="telcontr">
   <input name="emailcontr">
   <button form="contruct-from" type="submit">ОТПРАВИТЬ</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$('.btn-contruct').click(function(){
    if($("#contruct-from")[0].checkValidity()) {
        $.post('Post_Constructor.php', '&item_price=' + $('#price').text() + $('#contruct-from').serializeArray(), function(data) {

        });
            console.log('ok');
            return false;

        }
    });
```

**PHP-обработчик**

```
<?php
session_start();

new post_contact($_POST);

class post_contact 
{

public function __construct($post_data) 
{
    $this->send_contact_form($post_data);
}

function send_contact_form($post_data) 
{
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL .
'From: test@email.com <test@email.com>' . PHP_EOL;

$message = '<p>'.$_POST['namecontr'].'</p>';
$message .= '<p>'.$_POST['telcontr'].'</p>';
$message .= '<p>'.$_POST['emailcontr'].'</p>';
$message .= '<p>'.$_POST['item_price'].'</p>';

mail('test@email.com', 'Помогите пожалуйста', $message, $headers );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте

```
  $('#contruct-from').serialize()
```

вместо

```
 $('#contruct-from').serializeArray();
```

serializeArray() возвращает массив объектов, который можно передавать в формате JSONP, для получания строки запроса нужно использовать serialize()

отправка:

```
$.post('Post_Constructor.php',  'item_price=' + $('#price').text() +'&'+ $('#contruct-from').serialize(), function(data) {});
```

Comment: Сделал, сейчас получается вот такая штука: -----------------                                         NULL string(19) ----------"+38 (012) 345-67-89" string(14)------------ "test@email.com" string(19)------------- "900namecontr=ИМЯ"   -------------------------------- А на почту приходит вот что ------------------------- +38 (012) 345-67-89
-------------------------
test@email.com
----------------------
900namecontr=ИМЯ

Comment: $.post('Post_Constructor.php',  'item_price=' + $('#price').text() +'&'+ $('#contruct-from').serialize(), function(data) {});

Comment: Спасибо большое. Всё работает на отменно. Интересно как бы теперь сделать так чтобы не приходило в спам)

Comment: используйте smtp